# SQL SERVER: Create table with named default constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'd like to create a table with a default constraint for a field. I know I can add a constraint after the table is created but I need to create the table and the named default constraint in one single command, like this

`create table table1(field1 varchar(25), constraint df_table1_field1 default('a')  for field1)`

Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    field1 varchar(25) CONSTRAINT [df_table1_field1] DEFAULT('a')
)
```

Have a look at MS Docs about [Specify Default Values for Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15), specifically this secion: [Named CONSTRAINT (T-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#named-constraint-t-sql)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.doc_exz (
      column_a INT,
      column_b INT CONSTRAINT DF_Doc_Exz_Column_B DEFAULT 50);
```

Comment: Awesome! I found out that I can have this also:  `create table table1(field1 varchar(25) constraint pk primary key constraint df_table1_field1 default('a') )` Thank you.